# Translate Laravel application with locale from user and without display parameters in URL

Tags: laravel

I am trying to launch a multilanguage application with Laravel.

I would like the user to choose the language of his application. To do this, I created a "language" column in my database that records the user's preferred locale.

I can recover his preferences by doing this

```
Auth::user()->language)
```

In my .blade file, do this doesn't work

```
@if(isset(Auth::user()->language))>
   {{ App::setLocale(Auth::user()->language) }}
@endif
```

I would like to find a way to translate my application according to the preference of the user but WITHOUT displaying the locale in the url.

Is it possible ? How? Thank you !

Comment: You need to submit the choice in a form and process it once the choice is made. App::setLocale won't work in view files.

Comment: This type of logic doesn't belong in a view.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to make middleware, i.e. 'LocaleSwitcher', with your code inside

```
App::setLocale(Auth::user()->language)
```

And attach it wherever you need